# Regex that does not match ( and ), but matches '(' and ')'

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

I am trying to fix a regular expression used in tokenization so as to match everything (including **'('** and **')'**, but not match **(** and **)** without being surrounded by apostrophes).

Use case examples which should be matched:

- '('AN')'
- '('AN
- AN')'
- ...and every other possibility involving '(' or ')' combined or not with any string

Currently, it looks like this:

```
[^\)\(]+
```

The most successful result I have obtained so far is:

```
[^\)\(]+|\'.*?\'
```

This manages to correctly match expressions like: **'('AN')'** , **'('** , **')'** , **AN** , **'('')'** , **'()'**.

**But** it fails for: **AN'('** , **AN')'** , **'('AN** , **')'AN**.

**NOTE:** I have done some research, and found that the regex engine involved is quite old (around 1980s) and is called **PCLNT** (I am not 100% sure about its name). I mention this because in some other situations when I dealt with regular expressions, the regex engines available online showed the correct result, but in my application it did not even compile.

Any help would be great, also if anyone knows anything about this possible engine and its documentation please guide me.

Comment: So you're looking for '(' OR ')' not '(' AND ')' ?

Comment: What result do you expect with strings which contain apostrophes in other forms? For example, a single apostrophe (or an odd number). What if there are other characters between the apostrophes, ir multiple parentheses? Please try to make your requirements as precise as possible.

Comment: What should match of `'('FOO)`?

Comment: Why is `'()'` a match? Is `'(FOO)'` a match too?

Comment: @Bohemian should match '('FOO .

Comment: @Bohemian yes, '(FOO)' is a match.

Comment: @rici I would expect it to work for a single apostrophe or for an odd number and in my most successful result presented above it does. So, expressions like 'A(' , ')A'  , ''' (an apostrophe between apostrophes) match fine the way I did it. Basically, the original part of the regex does not match '('  ')' because it excludes parentheses. In other words, I want to allow ( or/and ) as long as they are inside apostrophes.

Comment: It seems that you've done a good job of describing what scenarios your regex does and does not work for. However, it would help if you could show a complete list of possible/expected matches (simplified patterns) as well as some examples of what shouldn't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match a sequence of any combination of characters other than parentheses or anything between apostrophes. It then optionally matches a single apostrophe followed by any sequence of unspecial characters, in order to catch unpaired apostrophes:

```
([^()']*|'[^']*')*('[^'()]*)?
```

I know nothing about the regex library you are using, but I don't think there's anything out of the ordinary in that regex.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to match all my use cases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to match anything except a bracket without an adjacent apostrophe:

```
^('[()]|[()]'|[^()])+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/qajSL3r6XNZ2VO).

Note that you don’t have to escape brackets in a character class.

Comment: It does not compile in this way.

Comment: It compiles, but does not work as desired. I think this might be caused by the legacy engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is any string containing `'('` OR any string containing `')'`

```
.*(\'\(\').*|.*(\'\)\').*
```

[Example here](https://regexr.com/5qaue)

Comment: It fails for test'(') . In this particular case, I need it to match only test'(' , without the ) .